# Can you reuse AWS MQTT Javascript Client

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

In AWS under IoT they have a great javascript/Angular MQTT client that allows you to connect, subscribe, and publish. For an internal project POC and demonstration it would be great if i could reuse that client. I wanted to know if they made it available or a library that could be quickly used to reproduce similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to include MQTT in my projects has simply been using the [Paho MQTT open-source project](https://eclipse.org/paho/). There are plenty of client references there, including a [Javascript client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/).

Comment: Hey Preston, Thanks for your response. I saw this client and thanks for the suggestion. I dont know if you have been in AWS IoT MQTT Client but it is very nice. I was hoping to find it was open source or available to be reused for an internal testing tool.